# Netsuite workflow - How to show an alert or message on click of workflow button

Tags: netsuite

I am using workflow to add a custom button, on click of this button I need to show a message or alert.

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow with 2 states.  In the first state add an 'Add Button' action.  In the second state add a 'Show Message' action.  Then the critical bit: add a transition from State 1 to State 2 and set 'Execute On' to the button created in State 1.