# NetSuite Workflow > Show warning/alert message when workflow button is clicked

Tags: workflow, netsuite

I tried the steps used in this stackoverflow topic [Netsuite workflow - How to show an alert or message on click of workflow button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541332/netsuite-workflow-how-to-show-an-alert-or-message-on-click-of-workflow-button)

It says "Create a workflow with 2 states. In the first state add an 'Add Button' action. In the second state add a 'Show Message' action. Then the critical bit: add a transition from State 1 to State 2 and set 'Execute On' to the button created in State 1."

However, the answer didn't solve my query. The message is not displayed. Can you please help me how to achieve this?